# Going Home Screen of app in android?

Tags: android

I want to go to homePage of my application on clicking button where i was in inner  page.
Can any one tell me how to do that ?

Thanking you ,

Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating an `Application` class. In that class have a boolean field that is false by default. Every `Activity` should check if that field is true in `onResume()` and call `finish()` if it is true (except for the main activity that always sets the field to `false` in `onResume()`). You can even create a custom `Activity` that does this and then have all activities extend that activity.

Resources:

- http://d.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3

  > **The android.app.Application class**
  >
  > The android.app.Application is a base class for those who need to maintain global application state. It can be accessed via getApplication() from any Activity or Service. It has a couple of life-cycle methods and will be instantiated by Android automatically if your register it in AndroidManifest.xml.
- Reference: http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Stripped-down example:

**MyApp**

```
public class MyApp extends Application { public boolean goBack = false; }
```

**MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onResume() {
        if ( ((MyApp) getApplication()).goBack ) finish();
    }
}
```

**SomeActivity**

```
public class SomeActivity extends MyActivity {
    // nothing special here, it's all been implemented in MyActivity!
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onResume() {
        ((MyApp) getApplication()).goBack = false;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
[...] <application android:name=".MyApp" [...]> [...]
```

**Note:** You don't need to declare `MyActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` because it will never be launched directly (it will only be extended).

Answer (score 0):

On your button click event add the following lines of code

`moveTaskToBack(true);`

Comment: Its going to homescreen , but i need to swith to homePage of my app i.e; to MainActivity.

Comment: Oops i am sorry i did not read your question properly.... I think you already got a partial answer for the same. You can keep your parent activity as singleTask and when you call the home activity from somewhere else set this flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. So all activities inbetween them will get finished

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two ways of doing that (general concepts):

The first one would be to simply launch the home actvity again, if you don't mind having it re-created again, unless that activity is a "singleTask" or "singleInstance" activity.

The second one would be to close the top activity in the stack as long as it is not your home activity. I don't see an easy way to achieve that, maybe by finishing the current activity with a specific result that gets checked by the launching activity, who will in turn close and send the result until the home activity is reached.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the first "solution", as that will create an activity loop (main -> other -> main -> other -> main) which can be pretty annoying.

Comment: i tried 1st solution , as u said , loop formed , when i clicked back .

Comment: Please can u tell me how to proceed with  second solution  ?

Comment: if you call startActivityForResult(), you can expect a return value from the launched activity if you override onActivityResult(). You can then check whether you should close the current activity based on the returned value.